# Problems with Code 1.53.X on CentOS 7 (100% CPU)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos7

Since upgrading to the latest VS Code (1.53.2) on my CentOS 7 host recently (64-bit x86), code chews up 100% of a core, indefinitely, every time I ran it (no extension installed).

When I downgraded code to 1.52.0 everything was fine again, CPU utilisation was normal; but when I upgraded again to 1.53.2 (or 1.53.0), the same 100% CPU utilisation problem reemerged.

See the problem in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kicUYrwSY-A

Sounds like either something was broken in code 1.53.X, or could it be CentOS, now that Redhat is deprecating it. Hope someone has a solution, other than downgrading Code that is.

Comment: I have the same issue with VS code 1.53.2 and CentOS 7

Comment: I confirm this issue on CentoOS 7.

Answer (score 12):

In an unfortunately short-sighted move, in VSCode 1.53, Microsoft has dropped support for RHEL 7 and CentOS 7, the only LTS release for CentOS.

As I posted in [the GitHub issue comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115784), as an awkward workaround, you can lock VS Code to the last compatible version. Of course this means you won't get any upgrades for VS code on that machine (but you'll have the latest version that is still compatible with the machine).

Here are the specific steps for anyone else finding this problem and needing to pin VS Code to 1.52 in order to not have their toolchain completely disrupted:

1. First:

`sudo yum downgrade code-1.52.1-1608137084.el7.x86_64`

or if you don't have VS Code installed yet:

`sudo yum install code-1.52.1-1608137084.el7.x86_64`

2. Then:

`sudo yum install yum-plugin-versionlock`

(if the versionlock plugin isn't already installed)

3. Finally:

`sudo yum versionlock code`

(to lock it at 1.52)

Note that it's still possible to test more recent versions alongside 1.52 by installing [the nightly "insiders" build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), which installs a separate `code-insiders` command.

**UPDATE:** Microsoft [claims](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115784) to have resolved this in the latest code-insiders release (1.60.0), which should make it's way to the usual releases soon (probably in the "August" release about a week into September).  In the meantime, you can install the code-insiders release as a workaround.

Comment: **UPDATE 2 (Resolved):** The 1.60 version of VS Code has been released. It appears to resolve the problem.

If you have locked the 1.52 version, you can confirm that with:

`sudo yum versionlock list`

If that is the only version lock, to remove the lock to allow the upgrade, use:

`sudo yum versionlock clear`

Comment: Hai Vu, I'd appreciate marking this as the accepted answer if you consider it answered (and now resolved!). Thanks. -Paul

Answer (score 4):

VS Code as of 1.53 no longer supports the default C++ ABI of CentOS 7.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115784

Work arounds are:

1. Stay with version 1.52
2. Install a new version of C++
3. Upgrade to CentOS 8

The linked issue discusses these.

Comment: Thanks that explained the problem. I will stick with code1.52 for now, and research on upgrading c++. Upgrading centos is still a flatten, reinstall affair as far as I know, so that won't do for my server. Thanks pcarter :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have a working solution on our side with:

- CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
- Visual Studio Code 1.58.2

Instead of installing it with yum package manager, we install it through [snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io)

First, install Snap on CentOS:
https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-centos

```
sudo yum install epel-release -y
sudo yum install snapd -y
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

And then, install Visual Studio Code through Snap:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```